# Allow the user to toggle between 2 ways to display content on mobile?

Tags: mobile

So I have some page for a mobile app that I want to display a list of products. I have two options and I don't know what to choose:

1. Show items in a **grid** with a **large picture** and a **small description** (Assuming the phone is portrait, you can fit 2 items side by side, 2-3 rows, so there may be 4-6 items shown in the screen)
2. Show items in a **list**, with a **small picture** and a **medium-sized description** (Kind of like a playlist in Apple Music)

Seeing as how both options can be good, as the casual users may **prefer form over function** (preferring option 1) and that the more detail oriented users may prefer **function over form** (preferring option 2), I feel like I should offer an option for users to toggle between the two. That seems to be the most natural solution, given that I find it hard to pick between the two.

However, that would mean I would have some sort of toggle button on the page, which may take away from the experience itself, ruining the aesthetics of the page, and making it more complicated.

So what should I do?

1. **Show a grid of items, thus focusing on aesthetics** and potentially ruining the small minority of users who prefer more information
2. **Show a list of items, thus focusing on practicality**, benefiting the small amount of people that do want the information, but potentially making the app more uglier for everyone else
3. **Add a button to toggle between the two views (on the same page)**, focusing on practicality for everyone, but ruining aesthetics for everyone (extra unneccessary UI elements and cognitive overload)
4. **Add a button to toggle between the two views, but in the settings.** This doesn't ruin the page with an unnecessary additional toggle button, and gives users who wish to see more details, the option to do so, hidden in the settings, and gives the ordinary casual user the aesthetics that they prefer.
   However I feel as though this may confuse users even more, especially if there are situations where a user may look at/use another user's device and have some sort of unfamiliar UI. But maybe I'm just overthinking.

Answer (score 0):

According to Baymard research consumer electronics is a spec driven category, which benefits more from a list view. As, with more relevant specs you can help your users pick the item that is of relevance to them and reduce pogo-sticking between the pages.

It is conventional to place view switching on the page together with filtering or sorting options, if you have such.